# Unique constraint on table with existing data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Im looking to add a Unique constraint for 1 int column of an existing table with about 1/2 million rows or so.  Ive also seen mentions of using a filtered index.  However, aren't there issues creating a filtered index if you want to later (or already have) foreign keys that reference those columns?

Can I add a unique constraint if some of the rows already are invalid?  I want to stop further inserts if the constraint fails.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT UX_mycnstrtname UNIQUE([col1])
```

Actually, the above will fail if I already have records that are duplicates in one column.

So, with a filtered index, like so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UX_1PerX] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [TableID] ASC
)
WHERE (ID > 888876)
```

My question now is - will this cause any issues with foreign keys that reference this column (TableID) ?

Comment: what is the question here? If data is not unique then Unique constraint will fail

Answer (score 1):

By looking invalid rows that means you have duplicate records correct? you will get below error:

```
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.myTable' and the index name 'UX_mytable_num'. The duplicate key value is (1).
```

you need to make them unique create unique index.